# Meaning of negative exit codes

Tags: shell, exit-code

While executing a shell script file, it throws -33 exit code

What does exit code=-33 refer to in shell script file execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exit codes can only be 0-255. Any value outside this range simply wraps around:

```
$ sh -c 'exit -33'; echo $?
223
```

Apart from zero vs non-zero, there is no standard meaning for any specific exit code.

Comment: So does that mean exit code -33 is exit code 223? And what does exit code 223 mean? Is it out of memory?

Comment: There is no standard meaning for any specific exit code. You will need to examine the script or its documentation to figure out what it means by that, and the answer will only apply to that script